# Debugging UC Mini browser

Tags: javascript, css, html, uc-browser

I am doing a web application. While trying to open the webiste on UC mini browser in data saving mode from my mobile device the css styles are not getting compiled.Is there any way to debug?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There are no very good ways to debug it. UCMini (or UCWeb in light speed mode) is a remote proxy browser. As far I know, there is no debug console for it. The only thing you can do is throw JavaScript `alert()`s to try and debug various JS breakage issues.

But if you are concerned about a very weird layout. Keep in mind that you will never see a normal CSS in those modes. UCMini is not a normal browser. It's a Firefox 10 proxy engine that will shrink your content into a single column, in a similar way Opera Mini does in single column view mode.

A couple good other helpful things to know about that browser's context:

The target screen size is 800x600. So in portrait, it shrinks it all to approximately 600px (in one column), and 800px in landscape. And due to the Firefox 3-10(ish) engine, CSS support is limited.

Answer (score 1):

I could say about our experience (FareCompare.com). Nodejs consoles + Frontend (Dojo) alerts. That's all we could find for our few bugs.

P.S. Pay attention that UC is working in one page mode. As far as I know, it is impossible to open new tab there. window.open() works the same as location.replace( url ).